# Java convert hash to random string

Tags: java, string, hash, reduction

I'm trying to develop a reduction function for use within a rainbow table generator.

The basic principle behind a reduction function is that it takes in a hash, performs some calculations, and returns a string of a certain length.

At the moment I'm using SHA1 hashes, and I need to return a string with a length of three.  I need the string to be made up on any three random characters from:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

The major problem I'm facing is that any reduction function I write, always returns strings that have already been generated.  And a good reduction function will only return duplicate strings rarely.

Could anyone suggest any ideas on a way of accomplishing this?  Or any suggestions at all on hash to string manipulation would be great.

Thanks in advance

Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_it_simple_stupid) principle:

- An SHA is just a String
- The JDK hashcode for `String` is "random enough"
- `Integer` can render in any base

This single line of code does it:

```
public static String shortHash(String sha) {
    return Integer.toString(sha.hashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF, 36).substring(0, 3);
}
```

Note: The `& 0x7FFFFFFF` is to zero the sign bit (hash codes can be negative numbers, which would otherwise render with a leading minus sign).

#### Edit - Guaranteeing hash length

My original solution was naive - it didn't deal with the case when the `int` hash is less than `100` (base 36) - meaning it would print less than 3 chars. This code fixes that, while still keeping the value "random". It also avoids the `substring()` call, so performance should be better.

```
static int min = Integer.parseInt("100", 36);
static int range = Integer.parseInt("zzz", 36) - min;

public static String shortHash(String sha) {
    return Integer.toString(min + (sha.hashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF) % range, 36);
}
```

This code guarantees the final hash has 3 characters by forcing it to be between `100` and `zzz` - the lowest and highest 3-char hash in base 36, while still making it "random".

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an other wise answered question.  However, if I change the substring on your answer for (0, 3) to (0, 4), the number of substrings generated under 4 characters in length becomes quite an issue.  Also the function seems to run extremely slowly.  Could you offer an explanation as to why that is?

Comment: @JoshuaCraven OK - I've added more code that addresses your concerns. You raised good points too btw.

Answer (score 6):

So it sounds like you've got 20 digits of base 255 (the length of a SHA1 hash) that you need to map into three digits of base 36.  I would simply make a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) from the hash bytes, modulus 36^3, and return the string in base 36.

```
public static final BigInteger N36POW3 = new BigInteger(""+36*36*36));
public static String threeDigitBase36(byte[] bs) {
  return new BigInteger(bs).mod(N36POW3).toString(36);
}
// ...
threeDigitBase36(sha1("foo")); // => "96b"
threeDigitBase36(sha1("bar")); // => "y4t"
threeDigitBase36(sha1("bas")); // => "p55"
threeDigitBase36(sha1("zip")); // => "ej8"
```

Of course there will be collisions, as when you map any space into a smaller one, but the entropy should be better than something even sillier than the above solution.

Comment: My bad. I'll delete that answer. That's a property related with the existence of the inverse in a congruence relationship (something you don't need in this case).

Comment: Thank you very much, they are both super answers, but I've accepted the one from Bohemian as it's slightly shorter.  Thanks for all the comments though; once again the people on StackOverflow prove themselves to not be getting paid enough, whatever it is they are doing!!!

Comment: @JoshuaCraven: very welcome!  Note also that both my answer and Bohemian's might return a string of length 1, 2 or 3, so you'll want to pad the returned string with zeros if the length is less than 3.